# I can not store info in DB in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel

I have an issue with store info into the MySQL database, and I try to change the method that stores info into DB, but it still the same problem. Moreover, I need your help to figure out the problem and solve it.

**PostController**

```
<?php 
public function store(){
    $inputs= request()->validate([
        'title'=>'required|min:8|max:100',
        'post_image'=>'file',
        'body'=>'required'
    ]);
    if (request('post_image')){
        $inputs['post_image']=request('post_image')->store('images');
    }
    auth()->user()->posts()->create($inputs);
    return back();
}
```

**Post Model**

```
<?php
class Post extends Model
{
    //

    protected $guarded =[];
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
    public function getPostImageAttribute($value){
        return asset($value);
    }
}
```

**Form**

```
       <form action="{{route('post.store')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf
            <div class="form-group">
                <lable for="title">Title</lable>
                <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter title">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <lable for="file">File</lable>
                <input type="file" name="post_image" class="form-control-file" id="post_image" placeholder="Upload your image">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <lable for="exampleInputEmail"></lable>
                <textarea  name="body" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Submit</button>
        </form>
```

I appreciate your effort to help me, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what problem are you facing? is there an error?

Comment: No, I don't face any problem, but when I submit the form, nothing store in the DB.

Comment: what does happen when you submit the form? as if validation fails you would get redirected back, if you pass validation you would get redirected back, so is validation failing?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify title of question. See [ask]

Comment: @Gander Okay , I will update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the file of the request object you can access it via file() method. And why are you not using method injection for the request

```php
//use Illuminate\Http\Request; - import the use statement at top

public function store(Request $request){
    $inputs= $request->validate([
        'title'=>'required|min:8|max:100',
        //'post_image'=>'file',
        'body'=>'required'
    ]);
    if ($request->hasFile('post_image') && $request->file('post_image')->isValid()){
        $inputs['post_image'] = $request->file('post_image')->store('images');
    }
    auth()->user()->posts()->create($inputs);
    return back();
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's work now; also, I forgot to pass Request arguments into the store function. However, thank you for your helpful answer. Thanks